# Keycloak custom user provider

Tags: keycloak

I want to use keycloak in my Spring boot application, but I need user data in my business logic. I want to keep keycloak and business logic in different databases. I found a tutorial in here https://www.baeldung.com/java-keycloak-custom-user-providers
I use bitnami/keycloak in docker environment but in this image doesn't contains custom-user-provider option. It contains ldap and kerberos only. How can I add this option to bitnami/keycloak or is there a docker image of keycloak which contains this option?

thx
Zamek